# Thrift binary protocol bug

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm trying to use thrift for python / java interop. I decided to use the binary protocol as a default.

When I'm calling a java service from python, everything works fine. However, if I call a python service from java, then there seems to be an encoding error (which isn't present for other protocols - e.g. compact)

Generated python code has a function that processes every method name:

```py
 def str_to_binary(str_val):
        return bytes(str_val, 'utf8')
```

This results in an error `TypeError: encoding without a string argument` when called by Java.

The error seems to be due to the fact that python is expecting a utf8 encoded string there (which it'll convert to bytes), but java sends raw bytes (I see `b"method-name"` in the debugger).

Which of the two implementations is doing it correctly? In case of compact protocol, it is string, so I believe java binary protocol sending is at fault.

Comment: If the Java impl does not deliver UTF-8 then it may be a bug. Prepare a testcase and file a ticket.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are expecting and/or waiting for?

Comment: I encountered the same error. Have you already solve this issue?